# Query From Multiple tables with sum and case function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: TaskUser and PaperMaterial
TaskUser - Contains all users One column titled: User1) that could be a user in the PaperMaterial Table
PaperMaterial - Multi-column table where data could be written multiple times for the same user on multiple dates.

What I am trying to accomplish is a query that will show all users for a given date range and their total page count regardless if they have data in the papermaterial table.

IE:

```
Select Assigned_To, 
Case
When PaperMaterial.Assigned_To = TaskUser.User1 then sum(Page_Count)
When PaperMaterial.Assigned_To <> TaskUser.User1 then '0'
End as Count1
From PaperMaterial 
Inner Join TaskUser
on TaskUser.User1 = PaperMaterial.Assigned_To
Where Date_Assigned between ('06/09/2014') and ('06/13/2014')
Order By Assigned_To
```

Now, obviously this code does not work, because I am new to SQL and I am not very good yet. However, you should be able to see the goal here. which is:

Mike 0
Bob 200
Jen 0
Betty 125
so on, so forth

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do the trick

```
SELECT a.User1, ifnull(sum(Page_Count),0) AS Count1
From TaskUser AS a
LEFT JOIN PaperMaterial AS b
ON b.Assigned_To = a.User1
Where Date_Assigned between DATE('2014-06-09') AND DATE('2014-06-13')
GROUP BY a.User1
Order By a.User1
```

You might need to tweak the Date_Assigned logic, depending on your date formats... but the current clause you're using doesn't really make a lot of sense. I think the one above should do the job, assuming your Date_Assigned variable is formatted as a date or datetime

Comment: Thank you, it works halfway. Currently, it only shows the users that have data in papermaterial. I want to show all users regardless of the data in papermaterial. If someone has no data, i still want to see their name from task user, but the count should obviously be 0.

Comment: I've edited it to reflect a LEFT JOIN (eg http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)

Comment: I had to change to isnull because ifnull is not part of sqlserver. But alas, it is still only giving results of those who have page counts.

Comment: This question is tagged MySQL... not SQL Server. Use COALESCE (sum(page_count),0)